# Cannibalizing modern buildings in the Pacific Northwest

Tags: post-apocalypse, construction

A nuclear apocalypse destroys the world and most major cities are destroyed. Urban centers range from smoldering craters to almost untouched due to lack of strategic importance. What I'm concerned about are those in the middle, urban centers which have been left in ruin by nuclear warfare, but not totally destroyed.

When Tenochtitlan, the capital of the Aztecs, was razed by the Spaniards and their allies the ruins of the city were used to build Mexico City on top of it.

How feasible would that be, to recycle destroyed building, with the modern buildings found in the pacific northwest without the use of modern industrial equipment? Would it be more convenient to just find new materials to work with?

Comment: (1) Many users of this site do not live in the USA. For us, "northwest Pacific" means places like Kamchatka, Okhotsk, or Sakhalin. It took me a few minutes to realize that by "Pacific northwest" this question probably means places like Seattle and Vancouver, which from my point of view are on the north**eastern** shore of the Pacific. (2) Instead of using such vague terms as "modern buildings found in the pacific northwest" it would be much better to actually describe what kind of buildings you mean. The only building in Seattle known worldwide is the Space Needle. Made of reusable steel.

Comment: @AlexP -- To be fair, she did say "Pacific Northwest" and not "northwest(ern) Pacific". Like "New England" and "Midatlantic" it's a fairly specific and well known regional name. Also pretty singular, as there is no "Pacific Southwest".

Comment: @elemtilas: The difference being that I know immediately what New England is, whereas for this Pacific Northwest I had to stop and think. (And I still have only a very fuzzy understanding. Is British Columbia part of the Pacific Northwest? Or is the name applied only to the northwestern corner of the contiguous part of the USA?) (And I definitely cannot think of anything like a "typical construction style" for the region.)

Comment: Recycling depends upon the building materials, not the building location. Are you saying that you don't know what materials are used to construct buildings in Seattle and Vancouver? Are you expecting an answer detailing those materials, and how those materials have changed over the past 150 years? How is "ruin" different from "destroyed" in your mind? It's unclear what a good answer should include.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the idea of scavenging materials from cities after a nuclear apocalypse - the whole point of a nuclear apocalypse is to *destroy* cities, something that by all accounts it would be quite good at. No matter what a "modern" building is made of, it won't be much help after it's atomized.

Comment: @AlexP --- Well, now you know! As an American, though, I can inform you that even I don't know what *specifically* constitutes the Pacific Northwest. And I also think it's not that important. I don't see anything in the query about "typical construction styles" though. Would be nice, though, if the OP could clarify why the interest in that area as opposed to another area.

Comment: how long  has it been, what is tech level of the scavengers, what are they trying to scavenge? without a time frame and a lot more context this is unanswerable.

Comment: @elemtilas As I foreigner I did not have problems in identifying the area although it's borders are unclear to me. Is British Columbia included? Anyway I suppose OP refers to mainly concrete / brick building that may be more common in US NW rather than the states in the South (just an assumption of mine, don't have any actual statistics about that). This question needs some working but could be reopened.

Comment: @Llanez Please be more specific about the kind of buildings you have in mind and the kind of technology available. Do they have fuel? Electricity? Reusing wood parts would be straightforward with hand tools (but quicker with power tools). Most of all keep in mind: what are these people priorities?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing has to be where to build a new place to live. That will depend on the food source. A deep question will be whether or not any of the dams will have survived. Those dams currently provide power and water for farm irrigation. If no dams survived, then you are looking at fish and limited farming. Your living will be near the coast - very likely not where we have the cities today.

Unless you have a reason to live in the destroyed city, then there is no reason to even try to salvage anything from them. Building with the abundant cedar and fir trees is a lot easier.

Comment: To put this in perspective, look at all the "ghost towns" in America and ask why people haven't scavenged all the buildings in them. It is because people are choosing to live elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

**Some modern buildings in the Pacific NW have been engineered to resist earthquakes.**

https://www.oregon.gov/ccb/homeowner/Pages/earthquake-retrofit.aspx

These retrofits generally involve how the walls are attached to the foundation.  The skeleton of such a building would still be earthquake resistant.  Earthquakes will still happen after the apocalypse.  If by salvage you mean break up and use for some other building then no.  But rehabbing and reinhabiting an earthquake resistant building could make sense.

Comment: It would make sense to reuse as much as possible in a post-apocalypse scenario. Buildings included. OP needs to clarify what these people priorities are and what kind of resources they have. Also the timeframe of reference is relevant. Are we talking about immediate aftermath or generations after the event?